# CSS/HTML 2 Columns with sticky footer in the left column

Tags: html, css

I would like to create something like this:

[image: Image 1]

I need two columns: the column on the right will be a slider that should take `50%` of the width of  the page and `100%` of the `height`. On the left the content area should scroll (I'm using an `iFrame` for that) and the footer should be sticky at the bottom of the page (I've positioned it absolute with `bottom:0`).

Now the problem is that I don't want to give the content a `fixed height`, but the footer should always be `200px`, so if the window gets smaller in height it should look like this:

[image: Image 2]

Any ideas how I could do that?

Comment: Can you post your code? or make a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9HE3h/1/ --> You can't see the result though because I'm using two external files. But at least you can see the code a bit better...hope this helps.

Comment: Something like this: http://jsbin.com/masokalo/4/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/PFcUa/ ?

I used calc:

```
.cutter {
    background: orange;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

So it only works ie9+

Comment: Aaah! Perfect! Worked like a charm! Thanks so much, Jonas!

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
column {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#left, #right{width: 50%;} /* more or less depends on the margin */
#footer{height:200px;}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <div id = 'left' class = 'column'>
        <div id = 'content'>
        <div id = 'footer'>
    </div>
    <div id = 'right' class = 'column'></div>
</div>
```